# Python pyqt Change Position of Qtabs

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Hello World i am looking to make a Qtab Layout on my gui here and i have been looking around to see how i would change the tabs to be registered down at the bottom of my screen like shown in the Red pen in my image. leaving where the blue pen is marked as a place i can wright info about the program that dose not change when you click on a new tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [QVBoxLayout](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvboxlayout.html) as your top-level widget. Then add the two controls to the layout.

This will automatically stack the two widgets in the manner you are asking.

If you want additional layouts, then you add more layouts.

For example, to split the top half of the form into two, instead of:

```
adding a QVBoxLayout as the top control, then adding a QTextEdit and a QTabWidget control
```

Do this:

```
add a QVBoxLayout as the top control, then add a QHBoxLayout and a QTabWidget. Then add your picture widget and a QTextEdit to the QHBoxLayout.
```

You need to read the [basics of Qt's layout.](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/)

Comment: I have amended my answer with commentary.

Comment: If you happened to be someone who downvoted me for this answer, could you please explain why?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a layout that should point you in the right direction. It was built using the [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) tool and converted to .py using pyuic5:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 791, 551))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "Here's some text that won't change based on the tabs"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))
```